# GRAILS 2.0 Exception :- java.lang.VerifyError: (class: xls/Recruitment, method: initErrors signature: ()V) Unable to pop operand off an empty stack

Tags: grails, grails-2.0

I am trying to run grails application and I get below exception

SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.GrailsContextLoaderListener

```
**org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'grailsApplication' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.VerifyError: (class: xls/Recruitment, method: initErrors signature: ()V) Unable to pop operand off an empty stack**

    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

**Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: (class: xls/Recruitment, method: initErrors signature: ()V) Unable to pop operand off an empty stack**

    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247)
    ... 5 more
```

I am using grails 2.0 and Recruitment class mentioned in the exception is domain class.

```
package xls

class Recruitment implements Serializable {

    String id
    String position
    String candidateName
    String noticePeriod
    String hrAgencyName
    String cellPhone
    String profileSourcingData
    String totalWorkExperience
    String emailAddress
    String currentCTC
    String expectedCTC
    String currentPosition
    String currentOrganisationName
    String communication
    String bankingOrFinancialDomainKnowledge
    String clientManagementExperience
    String reasonForChange
    String firstInterviewBy
    String secondInterviewBy
    String interviewStatus
    String offerDate
    String expectedDateOfJoining
    String joiningTeamName

    static constraints = {
         position(blank:true, nullable:true)
         candidateName(blank:true, nullable:true)
         noticePeriod(blank:true, nullable:true)
         hrAgencyName(blank:true, nullable:true)
         cellPhone(blank:true, nullable:true)
         profileSourcingData(blank:true, nullable:true)
         emailAddress(blank:true, nullable:true)
         totalWorkExperience(blank:true, nullable:true)
         currentCTC(blank:true, nullable:true)
         expectedCTC(blank:true, nullable:true)
         currentPosition(blank:true, nullable:true)
         currentOrganisationName(blank:true, nullable:true)
         communication(blank:true, nullable:true)
         bankingOrFinancialDomainKnowledge(blank:true, nullable:true)
         clientManagementExperience(blank:true, nullable:true)
         reasonForChange(blank:true, nullable:true)
         firstInterviewBy(blank:true, nullable:true)
         secondInterviewBy(blank:true, nullable:true)
         interviewStatus(blank:true, nullable:true)
         offerDate(blank:true, nullable:true)
         expectedDateOfJoining(blank:true, nullable:true)
         joiningTeamName(blank:true, nullable:true)
    }


    static mapping = {
            id generator:'assigned'

     }


}
```

Comment: I just copied this verbatim and was able to generate controller/views, run the app and see the views ok. So I don't think the class definition in and of itself is the problem.  First thing usually suggested is to do a `grails clean` and try again. I also saw some things that indicated that it could be a conflict between libraries it is compiled with versus runtime. The problem there was having a different groovy version in the path versus what Grails uses.  If the clean doesn't work maybe check that.

Comment: Hi Kelly .... I tried grails clean before but it didn't work. Actually u were right. Path to grails was pointing to grails 1.3.7 version whereas I was working on grails 2.0. So I changed the path but I am still facing the same issue .... Any idea what could be the problem here?

Comment: What about Groovy?  Grails 2 is supplied with Groovy 1.8.6.  Does your OS have a GROOVY_HOME defined to a different version, of is a different Groovy version in the path?

Comment: I was using grails 1.3.7 with groovy 1.7. Then I started working on grails 2.0 but did not change groovy version. So I changed the groovy version to 1.8 and managed to create war and deploy in Tomcat... Thanks for your help Kelly...

Comment: I'm going to create an answer so the question can be seen as done.  You can accept my answer if you feel it is appropriate.

Answer (score 3):

I got a java.lang.VerifyError in a Grails 2.2.0 app due to a commented-out Groovy expression in a GSP file that apparently made the Grails caching mechanism break. Removing the commented-out expression fixed the issue.

Comment: Thank you! You have saved me hours.

Answer (score 2):

Please check version conflicts between compilation and deployment jars, particularly `groovy-all.jar`

Comment: I got a java.lang.VerifyError in a Grails 2.2.0 app due to a commented-out code Groovy expression in a GSP file that apparently made the Grails caching mechanism break. Removing the commented-out expression fixed the issue.

Comment: @miek your comment finally helped me fix this weird problem - you should probably post it as answer...

Comment: @jako512 glad to hear that helped! Thanks for the suggestion, posted it as an answer.